# Linear Algebra True/False change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a few true and false I need help with. I have an explanation for some but I am not sure they are correct

1. [image]  I think this is false because if you set P and H next to each other and reduce to echelon form you get a change of basis matrix that is 3X2 not 3X3
2. [image] I think this is true
3. If A is a change of basis matrix, then A is similar to a diagonal matrix. I think this is false because the condition (has a basis consisting of eigenvectors of A) is not present.

Comment: Well for 1) every change of basis matrix is invertible (why?), so what you can say about $Q$. For 2) let $[T]_C= [I_V T I_V]_C=[I_V]_B^C[T]_B[I_V]_C^B$, and what you could say about $[I_V]_C^B$ and $[I_V]_B^C$.

Comment: oh ok so 1 is false because 0 is not invertible

Comment: and number two would be false correct because the example you gave me are inverses not similar

Comment: What is your definition of similar is not $A$ is similar to $B$, $\iff A= QBQ^{-1}$ or sometime equivalent so what happens to $[I_V]_B^C$ and $[I_V]_C^B$ and in gral to the transformation when is see with $B$ or $C$ doen't have this form?

Comment: and you need to proof that any change of bases matrix is invertible, is not difficult at all

Comment: is my explanation for number 3 correct?

Comment: You can give a counterexample, construct a matrix of change of basis (invertible matrix) which is not diagonalizable. (2 is correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1) every change of basis matrix is invertible (why? ). For 2) let $B,C$ be bases for $V$ so $[T]_C= [IvTIv]_C=[Iv]_B^C[T]_B[Iv]_C^B$, so let $Q=[Iv]_C^B$, then $Q^{-1}=[Iv]_B^C$ (why?), then $[T]_C=Q^{-1}[T]_BQ$, and hence we can conclude that$[T]_C$ and $[T]_B$ are similar. For 3) clearly $B=\{(1,0) (1,1)\}$ is a basis for $F^2$ and also

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 \\
   0 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

is the change of basis from $B$ to the standard basis of $F^2$ (why?) also $A$ is not diagonalizable (why?), then is not similar to a diagonal matrix.